# Need to change appspot subdomain to custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname

i want to change to a custom domain for my google app engine website.
I know already that i need to setup my records to CNAME at my domain provider for my already registered domain,
but i cannot find at the google app engine website where i can add a domain alias for my app.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your google cloud account, click on your project, then go to compute, then app engine, then settings, then custom domains, then click 'add a custom domain', and here is where you can add an alias or subdomain to a domain you have already verified.